# getting the end of an web address in c?

Tags: c

say I pass an argument www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-11893886
I need to separate www.bbc.co.uk from /news/world-us-canada-11893886 for a HTTP GET

I have tried using strtok and strcat but I come across weird splits at runtime.
I can get www.bbc.co.uk just fine using strtok( host, "/");

I have tried using a combination of strtok and strcat to try and get all the rest of the string from the first "/" but i get an output like this...
request: da-11893886
tempString: news/world!
host: www.bbc.co.uk
Path: news/world!da-11893886

If you look at this output, the strangest part is that it always cuts out the middle section.
In this case, the "-us-cana"

the section of the code is attached below

```
// testing purposes
 printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1] );

 host = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));
 strcpy(host, argv[1]);
 host = strtok(host, "/");

 // get the request
 request = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]) + sizeof(char)*6);

 char *tok, *tempString;
 tempString = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));

 tok = strtok( NULL, "\0");

 while( tok ) {
  strcpy(tempString, tok);
  printf("request: %s\n", request);
  request = strcat(tempString, request);
  tok = strtok(NULL, "\0");
 }

 printf("host: %s\n", host);
 printf("Path: %s\n", request);
```

Thanks for looking over this.
Any direction or even a link to a site where I can figure out how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  I have modified your code to work the way you are expecting
> ```

```
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    char *request,*host,*req;
     char *tok, *tempString;
    printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1] );

    host = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
     strcpy(host, argv[1]);
     host = strtok(host, "/");


     tempString = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));

     tok = strtok( NULL, "\0");
     printf("sizeof(tok) %d\n",strlen(tok));
      strncpy(tempString, tok,strlen(tok));

     while( tok ) {
      tok = strtok(NULL, "\0");
      if (tok != NULL) {
      strncat(tempString, tok,strlen(tok));
      }else {
       break;
      }
     }
     request = tempString;
     printf("host: %s\n", host);
     printf("Path: %s\n", request);
    }
    ~
```

> **Output**

```
./tmp www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-11893886/tmp.htmlargv[1]: www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-11893886/tmp.html
sizeof(tok) 38
host: www.bbc.co.uk
Path: news/world-us-canada-11893886/tmp.html
bash-2.03$
```

~

Comment: Your code has a few off-by-one errors. When you `malloc` based upon `strlen` you need to add 1 to the result as `strlen` does *not* count the terminating NUL character.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that does more than you want. Note that this modifies the original string - you may want to make copies instead:

```
void split_request(char *request, char **protocol, char **addr, char **path)
{
  char *ptr = strstr(request, "://");

  if(NULL == ptr)
  {
    *protocol = NULL;
    *addr = request;
  }
  else
  {
    *protocol = request;
    *addr = ptr + 3;
    *ptr = '\0';
  }

  ptr = strchr(*addr, '/');
  if(NULL == ptr)
  {
    *path = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    *path = ptr + 1;
    *ptr = '\0';
  }
}
```

Please excuse any typos/obvious errors. I'm typing this in a hurry as I have work to do :P
 It should get you started though.

Comment: If you're going to hold other peoples' code to the fire, then there is no excuse for you to not hold yourself to the same standards. This code is completely broken.  I think even you'll agree that segfaults are worse than an unchecked buffer that has the *potential* to overflow.  Here are your errors: 1) `strstr()` will point to the ':' in '://' so you need to add 3, not 1 to `ptr` 2) You want to pass `*addr` to `strchr()`, not `addr`.  Please revise and I will give +1

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. Well spotted. Post revised. I did say "Please excuse any typos/obvious errors" etc. etc. though.

Comment: I hope you can appreciate the hypocrisy of being critical on other peoples coding style but then attempt to hand wave your errors away with a blanket statement.  In other news, your revised code now works, here is your +1 as promised.

Comment: There's a difference between relatively trivial coding errors like typing a '1' when you meant a '3' or missing a '*' and more fundamental errors like ignoring a return value. The first is a typo, the second teaches a poor approach to coding. You could have just said something like "but remember to check return values and deal with them appropriately" or something. Also your example was misleading. Having said to use strrchr, you then ACTUALLY used strcspn to get the value he needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strrchr()` to find the last occurrence of '/' from the rear.  You will then have a pointer to the start of 'the end of the web address' if you add one to that returned pointer.

#### Update

Assuming your URL does not start with `http://`, this aught to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char url[] = "www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-11893886";
    int  cnt;
    char host[100];
    char path[100];
    char request[100];

    strcpy(request, strrchr(url, '/'));

    strcpy(host, url);
    host[cnt = strcspn(url, "/")] = '\0';

    strcpy(path, &url[cnt]);

    printf("host: %s\npath: %s\nrequest: %s\n", host, path, request);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./a.out
host: www.bbc.co.uk
path: /news/world-us-canada-11893886
request: /world-us-canada-11893886
```

Comment: Similar logic as in your answer can be applied when using strtok as well, with the token `/`. After the first match, you have a pointer to the "rest" of the URL.

Comment: As for http://, I did think about it but i figured i could do a strtok(argv[1], "/") with strcmp() to see if it's http:/ and then increment the pointer?

Comment: @James - this is generally fine, but (God is in the details...) if you have a match, then you don't just increment the pointer, but also need another iteration of the strtok(). Additionally, consider other protocols, like `https://`, `ftp://`, etc.

Comment: I "info'd strrchr" and double checked with the first query from google.

Comment: i am using "request = strrchr("/", *argv[1]);" and it is returning null. However, gcc compiles it fine. What am I not understanding about strrchr?

Comment: Switch the arguments around. And the second argument needs to be a character, not a string. `request = strrchr(argv[1], '/')`

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it. I did strrchr(argv[1], '/'). Thank you, that worked perfectly. My second issue is that while i get everything after the first '/' from reverse, how can I get the "/news" ? The only thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to keep on calling strrchr(argv[1], '/') in a while loop and strcat the output until the '/' matches the first '/' after www.bbc.co.uk

Comment: Don't use strrchr. The code example in this answer is poorly coded and not well thought out at all. See my answer below (although I'm assuming all you want to do is find the first / that isn't part of the protocol specifier). If you can comment on my answer and be more precise about exactly what you are trying to achieve I can come up with some code for you.

Answer (score 0):

strrchr() returns the LAST instance of the character. He wants the FIRST instance after any http:// string.

The answer is simple:

char *address_start = strchr(in_string+8, '/');

If it's non NULl then there you are at the first / of the path.

Why +8? Because "https://" is 8 characters long and even if there is no "http://" at the beginning, no IP or web address is less than 8 characters. Even "a.b.c.d" is 7 characters long and I don't believe an IPv4 dotted numerical notation has any legal public address with all single digits. I might be wrong though. Might be worth validating the string to check it's long enough first.

Anyway, you can always pre-validate the string to see if it begins with "http" or not to determine the offset to start searching at.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure how you determined my code is poorly coded and not thought out at all, you know, considering it solved his problem. `strrchr()` allows you to get the 'request' portion. 2) Never assume as it makes an ass out of you and... well just you. Surely `abc.com` is a valid host/domain less than 8 chars. 3) You probably should comment on the OP's question, not my answer, if your statements are directed to him

Comment: I didn't assume. I looked at your code and it is way more complicated than needed and doesn't solve his problem simply and cleanly. strrchr is CLEARLY the wrong function. You would have to call it once for each '/' character in the URL in order to reach the first one whereas the strchr will take you straight there in a single function call.

Comment: Oh and by the way, if the path is over 100 characters (and some definitely are) then you'll have a buffer overflow. If the first strrchr returns NULL, you'll get a segfault. Yeah, really good code there! Let's teach the beginner how to riddle his code with bugs, why not?

Comment: I would take a closer look at my code before you make such bold (and untrue) claims.  I only used `strrchr()` to get the *request* portion which if you took a closer examination of the code is the part of the URL past the *last* '/'.  To get the host portion I used `strcspn()` but I could have easily used `strchr()` in its place.

Comment: As to your overflow point, that is true. However, my code was meant to be an *example* on how to get portions of the string. Using dynamic memory allocation would have needlessly obfuscated the code. As the OP's current code already uses dynamic memory allocation I'm fairly certain he maintained that architecture.  You're not going to get very far on SO with a greater-than-thou attitude, especially when your points are unfounded. $0.02

Comment: My point exactly. Thankyou for making it for me. The OP asked "I need to separate www.bbc.co.uk from /news/world-us-canada-11893886". You said to use strrchr(), but IN FACT you used strcspn() to get that part of the address, and NOT strrchr(). You used strrchr() to just get "world-us-canada-11893886" which is not something he asked for. Hence it is "not well thought out at all". It's "poorly coded" because you used static buffers that might overflow and didn't check return pointers that might be NULL. My points were not unfounded, merely unexplained.

Comment: And you said "I'm fairly certain he maintained that architecture". That would be an assumption, right? After you previously said "Never assume as it makes an ass out of you and... well just you". I didn't assume anything at any stage...but you did. So who's the ass now?

Comment: Most assuredly you, that I can guarantee.

Comment: Although such things tend to be subjective, as far as they can be objective, and based on logic and not emotions and opinions, it's you. You stated that to make an assumption is to be an ass. You clearly made an assumption. I don't see that I made any assumptions. I never stated that to make assumptions is to be an ass, either. And since I don't much care for your opinion, yet by definition you must care about your own opinion, the only person here who can be an ass in his own opinion is you.

Comment: SO is meant to be website for learning and sharing, not a forum to compare your e-peen to others. If you felt you could do better than my answer then the appropriate initial response would have been to post your own and state why your answer is more appropriate. Instead, your initial response was to make ad hominem attacks. It was very clear you did not bother to read my code before you made your claims as you would have seen the `strcspn` call.  I think it was pretty clear that you made the *assumption* that a hard coded value of 8 would work in all cases (which it doesn't).

Comment: I agree it's a website for teaching and sharing and learning. I felt your example was misleading because your initial answer said to use strrchr but the example used strcspn (which I DID see from your code before I posted). I also felt your example was poor because it taught poor coding practice. In my job, on a daily basis, I deal with people who make my work very hard because they either don't understand or don't care or are just too damn lazy to approach coding with the right attitude - to write clean, clear, and correct code. These are values best taught when someone is first learning.